Ensuring Correct Page Numbering Side in Two-Sided LaTeX Document
I'm working on a two-sided LaTeX document with the following settings:
\documentclass[10pt, a4paper, twoside]{article}
\fancyfoot[LE, RO]{\thepage}

I aim to use Roman numerals for the initial pages (e.g., abstract and table of contents) and then switch to Arabic numerals for the main content. My current implementation is:
\pagenumbering{roman}
\tableofcontents
\pagenumbering{arabic}

This setup works, but I encounter an issue where the Arabic page numbering does not start on the correct side following the table of contents. Specifically, if the first page of the main content (with Arabic numbering) should be on the left side, the numbering incorrectly appears as if it were a right-side page.
Here's a minimal example that demonstrates the issue:
\documentclass[10pt, a4paper, twoside]{article}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\fancyfoot[LE, RO]{\thepage}
\pagestyle{fancy}

\begin{document}
\pagenumbering{roman}
\tableofcontents
\newpage
\pagenumbering{arabic}

\section{Introduction}
Content on the left-side page, but number appears on the right.
\end{document}

Does anyone know how to ensure that the Arabic page numbers correctly align on the left side when the first Arabic-numbered page is a left page? Any suggestions for proper implementation would be appreciated.

Welcome! Because the left page gets an odd page number, so it uses RO i.e. the right of the footer on odd-numbered pages.

Generally, odd numbered pages go on the right, and that appears to be what fancy header looks at.  Your problem is that you have page 1 on the left.  You could use \cleardoublepage instead of \newpage to have page 1 on the right, but that will introduce a blank page before page 1.

Note that the margins are all also wrong after the first page because everything assumes odd pages are righthand pages.

Although you lose some of the convenience of fancyhdr, you could simply use the centre space with \hfill. I tried to figure out what to patch in fancyhdr so the test worked regardless of page number, but failed miserably.
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper,twoside]{article}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{kantlipsum}
\fancyfoot[C]{\ifodd\ReadonlyShipoutCounter\thepage\hfill\else\hfill\thepage\fi}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\begin{document}
\pagenumbering{roman}
\tableofcontents
\newpage
\pagenumbering{arabic}

\section{Introduction}
Content on the left-side page, but number appears on the right.

\kant[1-10]
\end{document}

This positions the number according to whether the absolute number of pages is odd or even, as opposed to the page number displayed by \thepage.
